# Not getting response from post method in nodeJS to html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is my nodeJS code:

```
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
            res.status('500').send('showAlert');    
});
```

This is my Html post method call

```
$.post("/signup", userData, function(error){
        if(error.responseText == 'showAlert')
        {
            alert("User already exists");
        }
    });
```

Why am I not getting any alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Status code `500` is indicator of `Internal Server Error` which is handled in `error` handler of `ajax`.

[***`jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`***](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Refer this example:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

**Updated code:**

```js
$.post("/signup", userData, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}).fail(function(error) {
  if (error.responseText == 'showAlert') {
    alert("User already exists");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) is a reference to what status codes mean.

> Error 4xx, 5xx
>
> The 4xx codes are intended for cases in which the client seems to have
>   erred, and the 5xx codes for the cases in which the server is aware
>   that the server has erred. It is impossible to distinguish these cases
>   in general, so the difference is only informational.

Therefore, you should handle error response seperately.

```
$.post("/signup", userData, function(data) {
  console.log(data); // executed if status code starts from 2XX
 }).error(function(error) { // executed if error i.e status code 4xx or 5xx
 if (error.responseText == 'showAlert') {
  alert("User already exists");
 }
});
```